# Generating a schema from the JOOQ Metamodel in a different SQLDialect

Tags: java, database, ddl, jooq, dialect

I'm considering using jOOQ as a typesafe, DB dialect independent SQL generator, as I need to create a small database DDL script and a large number of INSERT- and UPDATE-statements on the fly from within a larger application. We then provide the file(s) as a download.

I've created the initial DB schema manually in MySQL and generated jOOQ classes to work with it. Currently, JOOQ is used to generate a bunch of inserts into an empty MySql schema). This works fine.

I would like to offer the user a selection of different DB schemes to export to: `sqlite`, `MySQL/Maria`, `Postgres`, and if the license is commercial, then maybe `Access`, `Oracle` etc. e.g.

```
    List<DSLContext> dbdialects = new ArrayList<DSLContext>();
    dbdialects.add(using(SQLDialect.MYSQL));
    dbdialects.add(using(SQLDialect.FIREBIRD));
    dbdialects.add(using(SQLDialect.SQLITE));
    //other dialects including MS Access available via commercial license.

    for (DSLContext create : dbdialects) {

        String dialect = create.configuration().dialect().toString();
        String sql = create.insertInto(EMPLOYEES)
                .set(EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME, fn)
                .set(EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME, ln)
                .getSQL(ParamType.INLINED);
        System.out.println(dialect + "\t" + sql);
    }
```

Of course, I can recreate the base schema by hand for each RDBMS, but this is tedious, error prone and it seems superfluous: is there not a clever way to use the generated Metamodel from jOOQ that I created with my MySQL DB schema to generate the schema for the other SQL dialects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality has been made available through the [`DSLContext.ddl()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#ddl-org.jooq.Table-) methods, which were added in jOOQ 3.8 with [#3160](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3160).

In order to generate and execute DDL queries (`CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT`, etc.), just pass the table name or schema name to the `ddl()` method as such:

```
Queries queries = DSL.using(configuration).ddl(EMPLOYEES);
for (Query query : queries)
    query.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - will definitely keep this framework on our radar!

Comment: @sprockets: Great! I'd love to learn more about your interesting use-case. If you're in for a quick chat, please contact us.

Comment: Is there any progress in latest version?

Comment: @PeterPenzov: Yes these features are available since jOOQ 3.8. I've updated the answer